# Why does `ethers.getSigners` return a signers array with the length of only 1?

Tags: unit-testing, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
...
const [owner, user1, user2, user3] = await ethers.getSigners();
console.log(user1, user2, user3);
```

I am using `ethers.getSigners` in hardhat test scenario. It should return many signers(I don't know how many exactly) but right now I can get only one signer which is `owner`.
I tried to print `user`, `user2`, and also `user3` and could see three `undefined` in my console.
Can anyone be aware of this solution?

Comment: Can you share your `hardhat.config.js`, and what network are you using for the testl? Anonymize any private keys and other sensitive data. But it should uncover how the signers accounts are generated (and how many of them are there).

Answer (score 3):

I kept resolving this issue using the favor of `google`, `github` and `stackoverflow`.
But I couldn't find the exact solution and this drove me to try to resolve this by myself.
I had another issue that `console.log` in solidity files didn't work at all in my hardhat test environment.
There was no errors in the solidity file and it compiled without any errors.
Then why? I look at my hardhat config file.

```
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";

import { HardhatUserConfig, task } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan";
import "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle";
import "@typechain/hardhat";
import "hardhat-gas-reporter";
import "solidity-coverage";

dotenv.config();

// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async (taskArgs, hre) => {
  const accounts = await hre.ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.4",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 1000,
      },
    },
  },
  defaultNetwork: 'rinkeby',
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      url: process.env.ROPSTEN_URL || "",
      accounts:
        process.env.PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
    },
    rinkeby: {
      url: process.env.RINKEBY_URL || "",
      accounts:
        process.env.PRIVATE_KEY !== undefined ? [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY] : [],
    },
  },
  gasReporter: {
    enabled: process.env.REPORT_GAS !== undefined,
    currency: "USD",
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY,
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 150000
  }
};

export default config;
```

Finally, I could find out the reason. That's because my hardhat is not running in my local network. It was running in `rinkeby` network.

Actually, that was correct solution for both of those two issues.

I recommend you not to update `defaultNetwork` in hardhat config.
You should mention network (`--network rinkeby`) instead in the command line.

Answer (score 1):

if you using await  it must be in an async function:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

async function main() {
    const [owner, user1, user2, user3] = await ethers.getSigners()
    console.log(`user1:`,user1); // or whatever output you want
}
main()
```